# django test.py changes the autoincrement of table

Tags: python, django

In the test.py

I make new entry `id=10000` for testing purpose(id is auto increment, current auto increment number is  36)

```
    temp = sm.mytable(id=10000,created_by="test",created_at=datetime.datetime.now())
    temp.save()
```

After test, this row is removed() automatically.

However autoincrement number start from 10000~

Why this happen?

database control in test.py affect the real database?

I need to change autoincrement number every time test script finished.

`ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = 38;`

My database is like this below

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        "NAME": config("DB_NAME"),
        "USER": config("DB_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": config("DB_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": config("DB_HOST"),
        "PORT": config("DB_PORT"),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        },
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'test_{0}'.format(config("DB_NAME")),
            'MIRROR': "default",
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your settings file? Specifically the database settings please.

Comment: Thank you @Swift, I updated the article. I use test database for testing. And the rows that are inserted in testing are removed automatically, but only autoincrement number remained

Comment: What is the output if you print `DATABASES('TEST')`

Comment: Do you drop the database and tables or keep them? When you delete objects it doesn't delete where the ID increment finished last.